# how to export from JqGrid data to excel without a server side call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

All the articles on the internet states that a server side call is required to export jqgrid to excel. I am looking for a mechanism where I could export once loaded grid to excel without having to make a call. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

You could capture a click event of an Export button and then loop through the jqgrid through javascript below:

```
$(':button[id=ExportExcel]').click(function () {
for (iRow = 0; iRow < cRows; iRow++) {
    row = rows[iRow];
    if ($(row).hasClass("jqgrow")) {
        cellsOfRow = row.cells;
            $(cellsOfRow[iCol]).text()

               // construct your html table here and then, combining code from below 
            }
       }:
```

Then use similar code to below to populate your table ready for export, but use the jqgrid data as the source instead of the html table created below.

```
function fnExcelReport()
{

    var tab_text="<table><tr>";
    var textRange;
    tab = document.getElementById('TableData'); // id of actual table on your page

    for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
    {   
        tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML;
        tab_text=tab_text+"</tr><tr>";
    }

    tab_text = tab_text+"</tr></table>";

    var txt = document.getElementById('txtArea1').contentWindow;
    txt.document.open("txt/html","replace");

    txt.document.write(tab_text);
    txt.document.close();
    txt.focus();
    tb = txt.document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"Say Thanks to Sumit.xls");
    return (tb);
    }
```